# Codefights subsequence

Tags: performance, time-limit-exceeded, r

I am solving https://codefights.com/challenge/Qjts7cukDvYpDW4Bc/main

My approach is simple. 
Get all subsequences by combination.
Simple loop over combinations.
Find minimum.

```
closestSequence2 <- function(a, b) {
LA = length(a);
LB = length(b);
minimum = Inf;

indexes = utils::combn(1:LB, LA);

for(i in 1:ncol(indexes)) 
{ 
 suma = (sum(abs(b[indexes[,i]]-a)));
 if(suma < minimum )
 {
   minimum = suma; 
 }
}  
return(minimum);   
}
```

I am not sure but I think it is failing due to the time because it pass the sample tests. Are there some easy tricks how to speed this up ot do I need different approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can speed up your code by replacing the `for` loop with more efficient (vectorized) functions. Your code can then be reduced to a simple one-liner:

```
closestSequence2 <- function(a, b) min(colSums(abs(combn(b, length(a)) - a)))
```

Looking at it step-by-step:

1. `combn` is applied directly to `b` rather than `1:b`. The output is a matrix where each column is a `length(a)`-long sub-sequence of `b`.
2. `combn() - a` takes advantage of R's recycling rules to compute, for each item in each sub-sequence, the signed distance to the corresponding element of `a`.
3. `abs()` converts to absolute (unsigned) distances.
4. `colSums` summarizes each column into a single value: the total distance from `a` for that sub-sequence.
5. `min` picks the minimum total distance across all candidates.

However, as pointed, an exhaustive search will not work well for large input vectors. A much faster approach is indeed to use dynamic programming. Here is a tentative implementation:

```
closestSequence2 <- function(a, b) {
  La <- length(a)
  Lb <- length(b)
  d <- abs(outer(a, b, FUN = `-`)) # matrix of all distances

  # x[1 + i, 1 + j] will hold the optimal distance between
  # the i first elements of a and the best sub-sequence
  # within the i+j first elements of b.
  x <- matrix(NA, La + 1, Lb - La + 1)
  x[ 1,  ] <- 0                             # init case where i = 0
  x[-1, 1] <- cumsum(d[cbind(1:La, 1:La)])  # init case where j = 0
  for (i in 1:La) {
     if (Lb > La) for (j in 1:(Lb - La)) {
        x[1 + i, 1 + j] <- min(x[1 + i, j],
                               x[i, 1 + j] + d[i, i + j])
     }
  }
  min(x[La + 1, ]) # min value on the last row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need another approach. Taking all combinations is the most simple solution, but the most slow.

You should use some dynamic programming techniques to solve this. I think there's solution in O(len(a)*len(b)) or something like this.